# Magento Search Box - Search by product id (entity_id)

Tags: magento, search, product

I want to enter the product id (entity_id) to standard search box (frontend) to find the product in my catalog. The default search can find a product by its sku but not by the product id. Can everyone help me if it is possible and how ??? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/search-by-product-id
or 
http://browsecode.me/search-products-in-catalog-by-product-id-magento/